# SQL Server Conditional Sort Performance Issue

Tags: sql-server, sorting, conditional-statements

I have a table and it have around 5 millions rows. When I try a conditional sort for this table, it takes around 25 secs, but when I change conditional sort to a certain sort criteria, it takes 1 second. Only difference like below;

```
--takes 1 second
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId DESC) AS RowNumber 

--takes around 25 seconds
CASE @SortColumn WHEN 'OrderId' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId DESC) AS RowNumber
```

Who can explain what is going on SQL server in this scenario?

Comment: Have you looked at the query plans in each situation? What are the differences? Could you post said plans?

Comment: Thanks @strickt01.  I can see difference only sort cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OrderId` must be indexed. Thus in the first instance:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId DESC) AS RowNumber
```

SQL does not need to perform a sort having originally performed an index scan on the `OrderId` column. It knows that the index is ordered by the column you want to order by so does not need to perform another sort.

However in the second example SQL has to evaluate `CASE @SortColumn WHEN 'OrderId' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId DESC) END` for each row. Thus it performs a Compute Scalar operation on each row to work out the result of the `CASE` statement. The results of this operation cannot be mapped to an index as they do not represent a column and a further sort operation is required. Over 5 million rows this is a very expensive operation.

If you were to run the queries over non-indexed columns:

```
--takes 25 second
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NonIndexedColumn DESC) AS RowNumber 

--takes around 25 seconds
CASE @SortColumn WHEN 'NonIndexedColumn' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NonIndexedColumn DESC) AS RowNumber
```

then both queries would presumably run equally slowly as SQL would have to sort in both instances (and not just used a sorted index). Thus passing in a column to sort by is always going to end up with slow performance over a large number of rows if someone picks a non-indexed column. You therefore need to ensure your results are filtered down to a manageable amount of rows prior to the `ORDER BY` being applied.

Comment: Thanks again @strickt01. OrderId column is PK and have index. I think you are right about scalar operation applied for each row, that make sense for me.

Comment: I will try some more different approaches to come over this performance issue, otherwise I will back to dynamic sql query approach.